# My car was towed out of the city to another county, do city laws apply to maximum fees?

Tags: traffic, washington, towing

My car was Towed out of Seattle and into Burien, the Seattle website listing maximum fees a towing company can charge says "From private property in Seattle", am I correct in reading that as the Seattle maximum applies and they aren't allowed to have charged me three times that amount for towing my vehicle?
As a side note is it worth disputing them claiming a 15m drive took them two hours or is that too hard to disprove?

Comment: https://www.kcba.org/For-the-Public/Free-Legal-Assistance

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you know that a 15 mile drive in Seattle can easily take 2 hours, which incidentally is not limited to driving time. The Seattle towing ordinance is [here](https://library.municode.com/wa/seattle/codes/municipal_code?nodeId=TIT6BURE_SUBTITLE_IVNELICO_CH6.214TOCOLIRE_6.214.220MAPRIMFETOSEUNTOSTAFURRE), with a more user-friendly explanation [here](https://www.seattle.gov/your-rights-as-a-customer/find-a-towed-car/max-towing-fees-private-property-impounds). Nothing in the ordinance addresses the distinction between "within Seattle" versus "from Seattle". Bear in mind that this is for impounded vehicles: if *you* want your car towed from Northgate to Burien, they can charge whatever they want. Also, Seattle and Burien are in the same county.

Comment: I should clarify it was 3miles, 15 minutes is how long it took me to go from the location of the tow to their business. I was charged for 2h for a 3 mile tow.